# Audience validation failed while listing azure storage account containers from app registrations

Tags: java, azure, rest, http, authentication

I am trying to get the details of azure storage account containers from rest API using the credentials of a an registered application in azure. I have built the authentication header parameter and when I am calling the rest API I get this error which says **Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.**

`19:47:16.826 [main] INFO  - <-- 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. https://shagundonotdeleteaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list (288 ms, 426-byte body)
19:47:16.828 [main] INFO  - 426-byte body:
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:deb7a983-401e-008d-30e7-0c884e000000
Time:2020-04-07T14:17:14.0081901Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
19:47:16.828 [main] INFO  - <-- END HTTP`

This is my code:

```
        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials("clientID",
                "domain", "secret", AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
RestClient restClient = new RestClient.Builder()
                .withBaseUrl(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
                .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
                .withReadTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY)
                .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
                .withCredentials(credentials).build();
   Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(restClient, credentials.domain()).withDefaultSubscription();
             Base64 base64 = new Base64();

  for (StorageAccount account : azure.storageAccounts().list()) {

            URL url = new URL("https://" + account.name() + ".blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list");
            StorageAccountKey key = account.getKeys().get(0);
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("GET\n"); // method
            sb.append('\n'); // md5 (optional)
            sb.append('\n'); // content type
            sb.append('\n'); // legacy date
            sb.append("x-ms-date:" + date + '\n'); // headers
            sb.append("x-ms-version:2017-11-09\n");
            sb.append("/" + account.name() + url.getPath() + "?comp=list");

            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(base64.decode(key.value()), "HmacSHA256"));

            String authKey = new String(base64.encode(mac.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))));
            String auth = "SharedKeyLite " + account.name() + ":" + authKey;
         OkHttpClient httpClient = restClient.httpClient();
         Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    //                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    //                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("x-ms-version", "2017-11-09")
                    .addHeader("x-ms-date", date)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", auth)
                    .get()
                    .build();

            okhttp3.Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            httpClient.newCall(request);

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Request Failed" + response.code() + "\n" + response.message());
            }
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            String apiResponse = response.body().string();

            if (apiResponse != null) {
                org.json.simple.JSONObject responseJSON = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(apiResponse);
                System.out.println(responseJSON);

            }

        }
```

This is the authsignstring

```
GET



x-ms-date:Tue, 07 Apr 2020 14:17:13 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-11-09
/mystorageaccount/?comp=list
```

I have tried this as well:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("GET\n"); // method
        sb.append('\n'); // content encoding
        sb.append('\n'); // content language
        sb.append('\n'); // content length
        sb.append('\n'); // md5 (optional)
        sb.append('\n'); // content type
        sb.append('\n'); // legacy date
        sb.append('\n'); // if-modified-since
        sb.append('\n'); // if-match
        sb.append('\n'); // if-none-match
        sb.append('\n'); // if-unmodified-since
        sb.append('\n'); // range
        sb.append("x-ms-date:" + date + '\n'); // headers
        sb.append("x-ms-version:2017-11-09\n");

        sb.append("/" + account.name() + "/" + "\ncomp:list");
```

and

```
String auth = "SharedKey " + account.name() + ":" + authKey;
```

Can you help me with this? I am stuck here from a long time.
I want the JSON response for the list of containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SharedKeyLite auth to call Azur blob rest api, please refer to the following code

```
 String StorageAccountName = "blobstorage0516";
         String StorageAccountKey = "";
        URL url = new URL("https://" + StorageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list");
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("GET\n"); // method
        sb.append("\n") ;//Content-MD5
        sb.append("\n") ;//Content-Type
        sb.append("\n") ;//data
        sb.append("x-ms-date:" + date + '\n'); // headers
        sb.append("x-ms-version:2017-11-09\n");
        sb.append("/" + StorageAccountName + url.getPath() + "?comp=list");
 System.out.println(sb.toString()); // print stringtosign
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(StorageAccountKey), "HmacSHA256");
        Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
        String authKey=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        String auth = "SharedKeyLite " + StorageAccountName + ":" + authKey;
        System.out.println(auth);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                             .url(url)
                             .method("GET", null)
                             .addHeader("x-ms-version", "2017-11-09")
                             .addHeader("x-ms-date", date)
                             .addHeader("Authorization", auth)
                             .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful()){

            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
```

[image]

---

## Update

When we use RestClient to call the Azure rest api, it will use Azure AD access token to do auth. [But the restclient use wrong resource to get Azure AD access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#azure-storage-resource-id). It uses `https://management.core.windows.net/` but we needs `https:\\storage.azure.com\`

My test code

```
 OkHttpClient httpClient = restClient.httpClient().newBuilder().build();
        //OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("x-ms-version", "2017-11-09")
                //.addHeader("x-ms-date", date)
                .build();
        //Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        okhttp3.Response response1 = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();



            System.out.println(response1.body().string());
```

[image]

[Analyze access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) via the [link](https://jwt.ms)
[image]

So if you want to use sharekey to call the api, please create a new httoclient.

Comment: Thank you @Jim Xu, In my question I have made a call through RestClient that I have builded, so how we can assure that the request is made by any authenticated system. And can you explain me what is the issue in my code?

Comment: @Sherlock21 According to my test, you do not use the right sdk to encode signature and access key. Please use the sdk `java.util.Base64` to implement it.

Comment: I have checked the code and corrected the Base64 import, still, I am getting the error that is Audience validation failed, after that when I've changed this line "OkHttpClient httpClient = restClient.httpClient();"  to "OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();" ,  the error is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to use the credentials of a registered application in azure. So, you may want to [Authorize access to blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

1. You need to grant your application access to your storage account

[image]

To be able to read your storage account, you need to at least add `Storage Blob Data Reader` role.

[image]

2. Acquire a token in your code, and use the token to access your storage account:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientId = "your application id here";
        String clientSecret = "application secret here";
        String tenantId = "your tenant id";
        String storageResource = "https://storage.azure.com/";
        String url = "https://{your_storage_account_name}.core.windows.net/?comp=list";

        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,
                tenantId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

        String token = credentials.getToken(storageResource);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-ms-version", "2017-11-09")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
    }
```

---

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have done this and credentials creation is working properly that's not the problem where I am stuck

Comment: This is also a good approach for getting the token. Thanks for sharing this.